# Ubuntu 16.04.1 - Live window resize lags a lot on GTX 1080

Tags: window, resize

Every window that I try to resize responds incredibly slowly. The windows in Chrome and Firefox are especially slow to resize and refresh. I even experience this delay in the terminal. I am absolutely dependent on instantaneous refreshes as I am working with responsive websites.

I run a GTX 1080 and a 1440p 144Hz monitor. Live resizing on Windows works flawlessy.

These are the things that I've tried so far, but that didn't help fixing my issue:

I uninstalled all of my existing NVIDIA drivers. I downloaded the proprietary 375.26 drivers for my 1080 from the NVIDIA download page. I continued to install this .run file via the terminal. Before that I tried the open-source 375.26 ones, but those didn't work either.

I changed my display rate to from 60Hz to 144Hz.

I installed the Compiz Configs Settings Manager. I made sure that the default resize mode is Normal (which basically means live window refresh on resize).

Comment: Can you show `lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA`? Just to make sure you're really using your gpu?

Comment: Yes the 1080 is the active GPU since it's the only graphics card that is installed on my system. I don't have integrated graphics as well.

Comment: Ok and can you see how much it is used when you resize a window? Like with `watch nvidia-smi` on a term and you resize a browser window to see if there is sth wrong with the GPU usage?

Comment: GPU utilization spikes up to 20-30% when I resize a window in Chrome.

Comment: I am tempted to reinstall Ubuntu

Comment: Update: I reinstalled Ubuntu. The bug is still present

Comment: I'm suspecting the desktop environment, maybe try Ubuntu without Unity like the Lubuntu distro, or even another distro. I've looked on google for your problem, it seems that users experiencing that problem were only able to fix it by using another desktop environment.

Comment: I installed Linux Mint. Thankfully the bug is gone. What a shame I really liked Ubuntu. Might try again sometime in the future. Thank you for your help

Comment: Mint is Ubuntu based so you'll probably be ok but if you liked the Unity desktop you can still look the other desktop available for Ubuntu(and their customization). Anyway good to know that it's fixed. Though I'd have liked to know what caused your problem.

Comment: I'll definitely look into making Mint feel as much like Ubuntu. It might have been updates that I failed to install properly or maybe it even were the drivers.  I might even extend my dual boot to a triple boot now to test that theory now that I have a stable Mint distro installed